Why does a table create in postgre shows a "black lock icon" next to all columns
I created a table in postgre using pgadmin4 but when trying to add data via the "add row" option in pgadmin it wont allow. The "add row" option is in disable state.
However looking through various threads and making some changes i.e. making column as "primary" in the table I can see the lock symbol goes away...
Checking the postgre docs i dont see it enforcing the "must-have" primary_key but suggests it as a good practise.
However i dont see pgadmin reflect this philosopy.
Am i missing out on something ?
Tried going through topics in stackoverflow and postgre  docs but doesnt give the clarity i need

Use a different tool, pgAdmin is just one of many, And imho not the best.

Ok.. any suggestions? Also is it a PGAdmin issue than a postgre issue (which i dont think it is)

psql is the one you always need, no GUI, but you need it. Most of the time I use DataGrip and in the past I used Navicat. Another well known tool, is DBeaver.

The solution is simple add a Primary Key to the table. You don't want to be doing inserts/updates/deletes without one regardless of the client being used. AFAIK most ORM's will not do those actions against a table without one.

The issue is probably that a limitation on updates to rows in grid view is spilling over to adding rows in pgAdmin.
When it comes to changing rows (i.e., UPDATEs), you can only reliably update a single row if there is a primary key to guarantee uniqueness. So if there isn't a primary key, updating rows will be disabled. Also note that if the primary key is excluded from the query generating the grid, pgAdmin will also lock editing in that situation as well. The same issue applies to deleting individual rows in grid view.
And so it would seem that in restricting "unsafe" updates/deletes in grid view (a reasonable precaution), the consequence of its implementation is that inserts aren't possible in grid view when there isn't a primary key.
